# Chance of hitting the same function at the same time by two Threads/Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, task

Assuming the following case:

```
public HashTable map = new HashTable();
public void Cache(String fileName) {
        if (!map.ContainsKey(fileName))
        {
            map.Add(fileName, new Object());
            _Cache(fileName);
        }
    }
}
private void _Cache(String fileName) {
        lock (map[fileName])
        {
            if (File Already Cached)
                return;
            else {
                cache file
            } 
        }
    }
```

When having the following consumers:

```
Task.Run(()=> {
    Cache("A");
});
Task.Run(()=> {
    Cache("A");
});
```

Would it be possible in any ways that the `Cache` method would throw a `Duplicate key` exception meaning that both tasks would hit the `map.add` method and try to add the same key??

Edit:

Would using the following data structure solve this concurrency problem?

```
public class HashMap<Key, Value>
{
    private HashSet<Key> Keys = new HashSet<Key>();
    private List<Value> Values = new List<Value>();
    public int Count => Keys.Count;
    public Boolean Add(Key key, Value value) {
        int oldCount = Keys.Count;
        Keys.Add(key);
        if (oldCount != Keys.Count) {
            Values.Add(value);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course it would be possible.  Consider the following fragment:

```
    if (!map.ContainsKey(fileName))
    {
        map.Add(fileName, new Object());
```

Thread 1 may execute `if (!map.ContainsKey(fileName))` and find that the map does not contain the key, so it will proceed to add it, but before it gets the chance to add it, Thread 2 may also execute `if (!map.ContainsKey(fileName))`, at which point it will also find that the map does not contain the key, so it will also proceed to add it.  Of course, that will fail.

**EDIT** (after clarifications)

So, the problem seems to be how to keep the main `map` locked for as little as possible, and how to prevent cached objects from being initialized twice.

This is a complex problem, so I cannot give you a ready-to-run answer that will work, (especially since I do not currently even have a C# development environment handy,) but generally speaking, I think that you should proceed as follows:

1. Fully guard your `map` with `lock()`.
2. Keep your `map` locked as little as possible; when an object is not found to be in the map, add an *empty* object to the map and exit the lock immediately.  This will ensure that this map will not become a point of contention for all requests coming in to the web server.
3. After the check-if-present-and-add-if-not fragment, you are holding an object which is guaranteed to be in the map.  However, this object may and may not be initialized at this point.  That's fine.  We will take care of that next.
4. Repeat the lock-and-check idiom, this time with the cached object:  every single incoming request interested in that specific object will need to lock it, check whether it is initialized, and if not, initialize it.  Of course, only the first request will suffer the penalty of initialization. Also, any requests that arrive before the object has been fully initialized will have to wait on their `lock` until the object is initialized.  But that's all very fine, that's exactly what you want.

Comment: That's right, another question, when having a series of concurrent tasks (for example to cache files). The Task_A tries to request `File_A` and Task_B tries to request `File_A` at the same time. Now I want to check if the file has been cached or not, if not cached, I want the Task_A to enter the lock, and I want Task_B to instead await the caching to complete. What do you recommend?

Comment: Your cache needs to be fully protected using the `synchronized` keyword.

Comment: It's C# not Java, I think that only applies to Java.

Comment: Whoops! C-:= let me restate that: Your cache needs to be fully protected using the `lock` keyword.

Comment: The problem is that, since this is supposed to be used within an ASP.Net Core MVC app, that will chain all requests which is bad.

Comment: Ah, I see now what you were trying to do, you were trying to lock on the specific filename only.

Comment: To be particular, I wanna cache files in memory, but the problem is to prevent a single file from being cached twice. The core problem is that two request may enter the lock and I don't want that to happen. It is a bit complicated. I hope you understand the case.

Comment: So, I take back what I wrote about `lock(map[filename])`, that one is correct.

Comment: But Mike, that is the exact area of the problem :D, you know you are 100% right, I tested that and it does throw the exception occasionally.

Comment: I amended my answer with something that you will hopefully find useful.

Comment: Judging by your original question, I think that's more or less what you originally had in mind, the difference being the fact that you cannot avoid locking your `map`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but the problem is that `map` cannot be locked! If so all requests will be chained. (that is horrible in a web app)

Comment: Requests will only be chained if the map is locked for a long time.  If the map is locked for a very short time, you are fine.  Long time vs short time here practically mean "time that you have no control over" (such as reading a file from disk) vs. "time that you have reasonable control over" (such as simply allocating an object and adding it to the map.)  So, the point is not to avoid locking, the point is to avoid loading the contents of the cache object from disk while keeping the map locked.

Comment: Mike, what I did was actually to create a data structure that cannot accept any duplicate without throwing an exception. I mean I have developed a hash map that if detecting a duplicate key it will simply ignore it. I think this way, I can concurrently check if the file is cached without entering a lock. If you don't mind, can we continue in chat?

Comment: No, your edit will not solve your concurrency problem.  Consider what will happen if one invocation of `Add()` gets preempted by another invocation of `Add()` right after `int oldCount = Keys.Count;` and before `Keys.Add(key);` Furthermore, `HashSet` is not thread-safe, so even `Keys.Add(key);` alone will crash and burn in a race condition.  Generally, there is no smart-pants hacky trick that you can do that will solve any concurrency problem, without using `lock()` or some other proper form of synchronization.

Comment: Yeah that's right. Since you mentioned that `HashSet` is not thread-safe, I made some search and I found that there are thread-safe collections built-in .Net Frameworks such as `ConcurrentDictionary` which has an `AddOrUpdate` method, though it provides control over updating or using the exiting value upon encountering a duplicate key. What do you think about this idea?

Comment: It is an excellent idea.  And guess what?  It makes *extensive* use of `lock()`.  Which you should just accept as a fact of life and get over your unreasonable notion that `lock()` causes pile-ups.  Bad use of `lock()` causes pile-ups.